# How to fix Fetch API Error in React Unity WebGL

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm trying to add Unity Game to React Website, but I got the following errors.

[image]

**Fetch API cannot load wasm://wasm/0767feb2:wasm-function[66388]:0x134031c. URL scheme "wasm" is not supported.**

Answer (score -1):

This alert show because there is unhandled error in unity game. (might occur when you passing data to unity game).